# Why aren't these variables stored in the order they're declared?

Tags: c++

I know it's probably unsafe code but for some reason, variable 2 is stored after variable 3 in memory. As you can see at the code below, variable 2 with the value 321 is declared first, however once we compile and run the program, the pointer to variable 2 is after the pointer to variable 3.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int variable_1 = 123;
    int variable_2 = 321;
    int variable_3 = 213;
    int variable_4[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    int *pointer1 = &variable_1;
    int *pointer2 = &variable_4[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << *pointer1 << ' ' 
                  << pointer1 << '\n';
        pointer1++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << *pointer2 << ' ' 
                  << pointer2 << '\n';
        pointer2++;
    }

    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
123 0x61fdfc
213 0x61fe00
321 0x61fe04
1 0x61fdd0
2 0x61fdd4
3 0x61fdd8
4 0x61fddc
5 0x61fde0
6 0x61fde4
7 0x61fde8
8 0x61fdec
9 0x61fdf0
10 0x61fdf4
```

Comment: The pointers have nothing to do with the order of initialization, that's just how the stack is organized.

Comment: The location of a variable is not necessarily related to initialization order.

Comment: If you want to test initialisation order, write a class that prints something in its constructor, and use that instead of ints. You'll see objects are initialised in the order they are declared.

Comment: Initialization order is the wrong term. I've edited your question to ask about declaration order instead. I presume that's what you're asking about, yes?

Comment: The c++ standard provides no specification of how local variables are stored. If you don't take the address of them they might not even be stored in memory and just be in registers instead

Comment: If you want to guarantee a bunch of variables are laid contiguously in memory, use an array, that's what they're for.

Comment: Or a struct/class

Answer (score 2):

There is simply no guarantee about the order of addresses of variables in C++ at all. That's how the language is specified. It is wrong to assume that there is any such relation between variables. The compiler is free to choose the address for any variable in whatever way it deems beneficial (as long as there are no disallowed storage overlaps, etc.).

That aside, incrementing `pointer1++;` and then dereferencing the resulting pointer or incrementing the pointer more than once like this causes undefined behavior. After one increment the pointer value is a one-past-the-object pointer for the variable which `pointer1` originally pointed to, which is allowed but not dereferencable. Pointer arithmetic beyond the one-past-the-object pointer is not allowed at all. Note that this is independent of whether there actually is another variable stored at the address of the one-past-the-end pointer.

Comment: iirc incrementing a pointer that doesn't point at an array is already UB. So the very first `pointer1++` is already wrong.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow For the purpose of pointer arithmetic an object which is not element of an array is considered to belong to an array of a single element, so that it makes sense again. See https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3.sentence-12.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4 clearly talks about objects that are explicitly part of an array *"an array object x"*, which would exclude incrementing pointers to single objects, and then somewhere else (your url) they say an object is the same as an array of 1. Do they have to purposefully make the standard harder to read?

Comment: PS: it's also mentioned in superscript 70 in expr.add.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think they don't like to repeat themselves in normative text and the description is already required in basic.compound to explain the possible values of pointer types. But yeah, I think there should be (non-normative) notes cross-linking in such cases. I should have probably linked the one in expr.add as well.

Comment: It's mentioned in the superscript so it's there. It's just easy to miss and they maybe could just have made the sentence itself different so it's not exclusive for arrays.